# Using ENUMs with Entity Framework Core Db First

Tags: entity-framework, enums, db-first

I have a PostgreSQL database in which several tables have fields which are enums.  I scaffolded the Db in a MVC Application but it skipped the enum columns although there is reference to them in the DbContext.cs file like this.

```html
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum("admin", "agreement_type", new[] { "Consultancy Agreement", "Saas Contract", "Purchase Order", "Informal", "MSA" })
                .HasPostgresEnum("admin", "invoice_status", new[] { "Pending", "Overdue", "Paid", "Cancelled" })
                .HasPostgresEnum("admin", "node_type", new[] { "standard", "study" })
                .HasPostgresEnum("admin", "role_type", new[] { "Program Lead", "IT Lead", "PI Lead", "Head Office Lead", "Contracts Lead", "Finance Lead", "Supply Chain Lead" })
                .HasPostgresEnum("admin", "study_type", new[] { "hiv", "vaccine" });
```

The models don't have them as they were 'skipped' so how do I fix this?  In the documentation it suggests adding the following to some static controller in my DbContext class:

```html
static MyDbContext()
    => NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<Mood>();
```

but I don't have any such controller. In the documentation it states:

> If you're creating your model from an existing database, the provider will recognize enums in your database, and scaffold the appropriate HasPostgresEnum() lines in your model. However, the scaffolding process has no knowledge of your CLR type, and will therefore skip your enum columns (warnings will be logged). You will have to create the CLR type, add the global mapping and add the properties to your entities.

but there is no explanation as to how to do this. Also there was no scaffolding of the appropriate HasPostgresEnum() lines in any of my models. So my question is, how do I create the CLR type, add the global mapping and add the properties to my entities?

Comment: I believe just putting the suggested static MyDbContext() assignment into  DbContext.cs on lines Before the OnModelCreating() override should be sufficient. You can break in the override and watch the static to ensure the typemapper is complete, i.e. has enums.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't recognize the name of the Enum.  And I don't believe that would be sufficient.  Wouldn't it also be necessary to modify the model?  Maybe the fact that the model is not correct is the reason it is not recognizing the enum field name